# Data overlaps when merging multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook which contains n sheets. I want to merge the data from each sheet to one single sheet. The header and data from the first sheet should be on top, the data from second sheet should be below it and so on. All the sheets have the same columns and headers structure. So, the header should appear only once i.e take header and data from first sheet and only data from remaining sheets. I have the following code:

```
Sub Combine()

'This macro will copy all rows from the first sheet
'(including headers)
'and on the next sheets will copy only the data
'(starting on row 2)

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim SheetCnt As Integer
Dim lstRow1 As Long
Dim lstRow2 As Long
Dim lstCol As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

On Error Resume Next

'Delete the Target Sheet on the document (in case it exists)
Sheets("Target").Delete
'Count the number of sheets on the Workbook
SheetCnt = Worksheets.Count

'Add the Target Sheet
Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(SheetCnt)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Target"
Set ws1 = Sheets("Target")
lstRow2 = 1
'Define the row where to start copying
'(first sheet will be row 1 to include headers)
j = 1

'Combine the sheets
For i = 1 To SheetCnt
    Worksheets(i).Select

    'check what is the last column with data
    lstCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'check what is the last row with data
    lstRow1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Define the range to copy
    Range("A2:G2" & j, Cells(lstRow1, lstCol)).Select

    'Copy the data
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("A2:G2" & lstRow2).PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
    'Define the new last row on the Target sheet
    lstRow2 = ws1.Cells(65535, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1


    'Define the row where to start copying
    '(2nd sheet onwards will be row 2 to only get data)
    j = 3
Next

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Sheets("Target").Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

With this code, my data from all sheets is getting overlapped. I want the data to be one below the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's overlapping because you don't increment the paste area on the Target sheet

To fix the problem offset the paste area correspondingly:

1. Sheet 1: copy 10 rows-paste -> increment paste start & end area by **10**
2. Sheet 2: copy 15 rows-paste -> increment paste start & end area by **25**: 10 + 15 and so on...

You can also replace this:

```
Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(SheetCnt)    'Add the Target Sheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Target"
Set ws1 = Sheets("Target")
```

with this:

```
Set ws1 = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(SheetCnt))   'Add the Target Sheet
ws1.Name = "Target"
```

If you eliminate all "Select" statements and refer to each object explicitly it will allow you to reduce code, and un-needed complexity

Here is my version:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Combine()
    Const HEADR As Byte = 1

    Dim i As Long, rngCurrent As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lCol As Long, lCel As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, toLRow As Long

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    For Each ws In Worksheets   'Delete Target Sheet if it exists
        With ws
            If .Name = "Target" Then
                .Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Set wsTarget = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    wsTarget.Name = "Target"

    Set lCel = GetMaxCell(Worksheets(1).UsedRange)
    If lCel.Row > 1 Then
        With Worksheets(1)
            'Expected: all sheets will have the same number of columns
            lCol = lCel.Column
            lRow = HEADR
            toLRow = HEADR

            .Range(.Cells(HEADR, 1), .Cells(HEADR, lCol)).Copy
            With wsTarget
                .Range(.Cells(HEADR, 1), .Cells(HEADR, lCol)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End With
        End With

        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count   'concatenate data ---------------------------
            Set lCel = GetMaxCell(Worksheets(i).UsedRange)
            If lCel.Row > 1 Then
                With Worksheets(i)
                    If .Name <> "Target" Then           'exclude the Target
                        toLRow = toLRow + lRow          'last row on Target
                        lRow = lCel.Row                 'last row on current
                        Set rngCurrent = .Range(.Cells(HEADR + 1, 1), _
                                                .Cells(lRow, lCol))
                        lRow = lRow - HEADR
                        With wsTarget
                            .Range(.Cells(toLRow, 1), _
                                   .Cells(toLRow + (lRow - HEADR), lCol)) = _
                                    rngCurrent.Value
                        End With
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
        With wsTarget
            .Columns.AutoFit
            .Range("A1").Select
        End With
        With Application
            .CutCopyMode = False
            .DisplayAlerts = True
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function GetMaxCell(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing) As Range

    'Returns the last cell containing a value, or A1 if Worksheet is empty

    Const NONEMPTY As String = "*"
    Dim lRow As Range, lCol As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        Set GetMaxCell = rng.Parent.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        With rng
            Set lRow = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                        After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            If Not lRow Is Nothing Then
                Set lCol = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

                Set GetMaxCell = .Parent.Cells(lRow.Row, lCol.Column)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Offsetting the paste area is done by incrementing lRow and toLRow

Edit:

If you use this code and you want to transfer cell formatting for all data cells replace this section:

```
'copy data to Target sheet
With wsTarget
    .Range(.Cells(toLRow, 1), .Cells(toLRow + (lRow - HEADR), lCol)) = _
        rngCurrent.Value
End With
```

with this:

```
'copy data to Target sheet
rngCurrent.Copy
With wsTarget
    With .Range(.Cells(toLRow, 1), .Cells(toLRow + (lRow - HEADR), lCol))
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End With
End With
```

but it will become slower if you're processing a lot of sheets

**EDIT**: to show how to handle special cases

The above solution is more generic and dynamically detects the last column and row containing data

The number of columns (and rows) to be processed can be manually updated. For example, if your sheets contain 43 columns with data, and you want to exclude the last 2 columns, make the following change to the script:

Line

**`Set lCel = GetMaxCell(Worksheets(1).UsedRange)`**

changes to

**`Set lCel = Worksheets(1).UsedRange("D41")`**

Comment: :It is working partially correct. With the original data,some garbage data is also being copied(named Errorcodeupdated).How do i avoid that?

Comment: My code will find the last row of data ever used. Your sheets probably have empty cells under the data, that contain forgotten formula, or cell formatting. If you press Ctrl + End on the sheets it will show what Excel considers the last used cell. If you see extra rows and columns delete them by selecting the entire rows, right-click on the left margin and select Delete. If you simply select the empty range and press Del it will not fix the problem. Remove all extra columns as well. If you have too many sheets to do this manually let me know and we'll fix it another way

Comment: please help me remove garbage data, i am unable to solve the issue as i have around more than 10 sheets

Comment: Ok, what doesn't work - doesn't copy anything? you want me to change it back the way it was? I can provide a script that cleans up the extra rows and columns in all sheets, but you'll need to open separate question for that

Comment: yes paul! it doesn't copy anything..please change it back to the way it was. And please help me remove the garbage data

Comment: I reverted all changes. Can you send me the file? If you'll ask  a new question about removing excess data from all sheets I'll provide a script that will clean the file

Comment: sorry i cannot share the file :/ Can u send me the script so that i can test it?

Comment: Sure: open a new question on this site, with this title: "VBA: How to clean excess formatting from all sheets of an Excel file" and I'll post a new script for that specific purpose, but I'll have to do it a bit later (I'm going to work now)

Comment: Thanks a lot! i have posted the question

Comment: **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846323/how-to-clean-excess-formatting-from-all-sheets-of-an-excel-file/30848369#30848369)** is a solution to remove empty and\or hidden cells containing only formatting, and unused formulas that can cause the "last used cell" on sheets to be inaccurate

Comment: I updated the code - please try it again. I improved the way it determines last column and last row. If you still have the same issue you need to find out exactly where the "Errorcodeupdated" is coming from: sheet1, sheet2, etc, and then the exact column and row on the sheet (if there are multiple cells containing it we just need to know about the first one). Please let me know

Comment: In my target sheet, Till column G is my useful data, column H and I contain garbage data.If you can  help me remove data on those two columns, it would be fine

Comment: So you have 2 extra columns of data (H and I) that you don't want to be copied to the target sheet (If is valid data, it's not garbage, it's just data not to be included in this process). This can be easily accomplished - I'll let you know when I get a chance to update it

Comment: Please see my last edit and let me know if you have any problems